# Unable to extract id from json response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My am calling POST on an API. The response has

```
{
  "id" : "1234”,
---
}
```

I have following regular expression extractor:
[image]

However in the DELETE HTTP Request on API/${id}, I am getting API/NOT FOUND.

Please suggest whats the issue with my regular expression ?

Comment: I fixed it using json extractor instead of regular expression extractor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence using regular expressions for it is not the best idea

Consider using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) instead, the relevant [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) expression is just `id`

Demo:

[image]